# Getting org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException for OneToMany mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am getting the following error while trying to save `Project` Object:

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated for:class com.assetproj.model.ProjectAssetType
```

My classes are:

**Project.java**

```
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<ProjectAssetType> projectAssetTypes = new HashSet<ProjectAssetType>(
        0);

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
@JoinTable(name = "tbl_project_asset_type", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "projectId") })
public Set<ProjectAssetType> getProjectAssetTypes() {
    return this.projectAssetTypes;
}

public void setProjectAssetTypes(
        Set<ProjectAssetType> projectAssetTypes) {
    this.projectAssetTypes = projectAssetTypes;
}
```

**ProjectAssetType.java**

```
private ProjectAssetTypeId id;
private AssetTypeMaster assetTypeMaster;
@JsonBackReference
private Project project;


@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "projectId", column = @Column(name = "projectId", nullable = false)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "assetTypeId", column = @Column(name = "assetTypeId", nullable = false)) })
public ProjectAssetTypeId getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(ProjectAssetTypeId id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "assetTypeId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public AssetTypeMaster getAssetTypeMaster() {
    return this.assetTypeMaster;
}

public void setAssetTypeMaster(AssetTypeMaster assetTypeMaster) {
    this.assetTypeMaster = assetTypeMaster;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "projectId", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Project getProject() {
    return this.project;
}

public void setProject(Project project) {
    this.project = project;
}
```

**ProjectAssetTypeId.java**

```
private long projectId;
private int assetTypeId;

public ProjectAssetTypeId() {
}

public ProjectAssetTypeId(long projectId, int assetTypeId) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
    this.assetTypeId = assetTypeId;
}

@Column(name = "projectId", nullable = false)
public long getProjectId() {
    return this.projectId;
}

public void setProjectId(long projectId) {
    this.projectId = projectId;
}

@Column(name = "assetTypeId", nullable = false)
public int getAssetTypeId() {
    return this.assetTypeId;
}

public void setAssetTypeId(int assetTypeId) {
    this.assetTypeId = assetTypeId;
}
```

All the pojos are created by Hibernate Tools. Is there any problem with my Mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have not mentioned AutoGeneration strategy for @Id,
like :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

So you need to explicitly set the ID in Pojo.